# React / Laravel (php) SPA on same (Apache) server

Tags: php, apache, laravel, reactjs, single-page-application

I want to do SPA application at the front-end will be the React, while the rest full api on laravel at the back-end. All I want to place on the same Apache server on the same domain ( myapp.com/index URLs my react application, requests will send to myapp.ru/api / ...).

Explain please, whether it is a normal practice, I understand I will have a problem with routing, and I always have to do rewrite to the index.html when page updating. Would not I have problems with the fact that I'm going to do ajax requests to the same domain as the front-end to the back-end.

Please explain that, and how that would all normally worked to configure. Or is it all a bad idea, and REACT to work on node.js server and separately laravel on apache. I would be very grateful for an explanation.

Comment: React doesn't care about your server. Just put it where you want and don't complicate things

Comment: Senks!!! But I have a problem with routing, when refresh page I have an error 404, I think, need to add rewrite rule, always redirect to index.html, yes? But I have a laravel routs from admin panel, Im not understan how to need configure my server. Or I need insert my component to markup which is located in my laravel views (index.php). Maybe you have link to example on git hub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPA application does not require a server.
You build your React app using webpack or browserify and server those static bundles to the client via Apache.

All the api calls will go to your backend laravel. (myapp.ru/api)

Comment: Senks!!! But I have a problem with routing, when refresh page I have an error 404, I think, need to add rewrite rule, always redirect to index.html, yes? But I have a laravel routs from admin panel, Im not understan how to need configure my server. Or I need insert my component to markup which is located in my laravel views (index.php). Maybe you have link to example on git hub.

Comment: I could not fully understand your scenario, I guess you are using laravel router with react router

To handle 404s caused by react-router use the following snippet in your
**app/Exceptions/Handler.php**, method **render()**

`if ($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
{
   abort(404); 
}
return response(view('react.app.view'));`

Comment: [Issue resolved of react routing inside laravel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135835/how-can-i-disable-laravel-routes-for-reactjs/41137777#41137777)